# Zones cannot load correctly

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I don't know where my zones have errors. I dont understand. after executing the named-checkzone command I get these responses. Could someone direct me to the correct vocabulary in the zone?

```
root@ubuntuserver:/etc/bind/zones# named-checkzone ns1.db /etc/bind/zones/ns1.db
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:14: ignoring out-of-zone data (ubuntuserver.com)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:15: ignoring out-of-zone data (ubuntumailsystem)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:16: ignoring out-of-zone data (clientnorbert.com)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:17: ignoring out-of-zone data (serverkerberos)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:18: ignoring out-of-zone data (adminserverkerberos)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:19: ignoring out-of-zone data (ubunturealm)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:21: ignoring out-of-zone data (ubuntuserver.com)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:22: ignoring out-of-zone data (clientnorbert.com)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:24: ignoring out-of-zone data (ubuntuserver.com)
/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db:25: ignoring out-of-zone data (clientnorbert.com)
zone ns1.db/IN: NS 'ns1.ubuntuserver.com.ns1.db' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone ns1.db/IN: not loaded due to errors.

; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.ubuntuserver.com. root.ubuntuserver.com. (
              2     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
 ; 
                    IN  NS  ns1.ubuntuserver.com
 ;
 ubuntuserver.com.  IN  A   10.0.2.5
 ubuntumailsystem.  IN  A   10.0.2.5
 clientnorbert.com. IN  A   10.0.2.6
 serverkerberos.        IN  A   10.0.2.5
 adminserverkerberos.   IN  A   10.0.2.5
 ubunturealm.       IN  A   10.0.2.5
;
ubuntuserver.com.   IN  MX  10  ubuntumailsystem.
clientnorbert.com.  IN  MX  10  ubuntuserver.com.
;
ubuntuserver.com.   3600    IN  AAAA    fe80::a00:27ff:feb5:df44
clientnorbert.com.  3600    IN  AAAA    fe80::a00:27ff:fe23:f7a1

root@ubuntuserver:/etc/bind/zones# named-checkzone db.0.10 /etc/bind/zones/db.0.10
dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/zones/db.0.10:14: near '.clientnorbert.com.': empty label
dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/zones/db.0.10:16: near '.ubuntuserver.com.': empty label
dns_rdata_fromtext: /etc/bind/zones/db.0.10:17: near '.clientnorbert.com.': empty label
zone db.0.10/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/zones/db.0.10 failed: empty label
zone db.0.10/IN: not loaded due to errors.


;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.ubuntuserver.com. root.ubuntuserver.com. (
              1     ; Serial
         604800     ; Refresh
          86400     ; Retry
        2419200     ; Expire
         604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
IN  NS  ns1.ubuntuserver.com.
IN  NS  .clientnorbert.com.
; PTR records
0.10    IN  PTR .ubuntuserver.com.
0.10    IN  PTR .clientnorbert.com.
```

Comment: Both in your question AND when testing please refrain from using random domain names and use either your *own domain* or one of the [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.5) reserved domain names such as  `example.com`, `example.org`  or similar . Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: You would do well to read a good intro into DNS before proceeding further. https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch2/ is old but covers quite a few of the relevant basics

Comment: Okay, I'll read this guide, it will definitely solve my problems. And I'll read this FAQ too, I care about the correctness of my questions, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Out-of-zone data is an error message warning you that your DNS zone file contains records that are not actually part of your zone, records that don't belong with the domain name the zone is supposed to describe.

[`named-checkzone`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/named-checkzone)`ns1.db /etc/bind/zones/ns1.db`

Checks the integrity of the zone file  `/etc/bind/zones/ns1.db` for records for the "zone" (in layman's terms for the "domain name")  `ns1.db`.

That expects domain name records that belong in the  `ns1.db` domain i.e. resource records like `ubuntuserver.ns1.db.` and   `ubunturealm.ns1.db` and not the records you have.

---

Instead of  `named-checkzone db.0.10 /etc/bind/zones/db.0.10` you would normally have to use the `0.10.in-addr.arpa.` zone name to check the syntax for the reverse DNS zone of the IP-address range 10.0.0.0/16:

```
named-checkzone  0.10.in-addr.arpa. /etc/bind/zones/db.0.10
```

Comment: Should you remove all domains and addresses not related to the ns1 domain to preserve its integrity. And where do I put the domains and addresses of the client that connects to bind9? In a different zone? In addition, executing this command with named-checkzone in arpa still shows an "empty label" error. I dont understood that end with ns1.db to ubunturealm.

Comment: Each domain for which your name server is authoritative requires set up in the ISC Bind configuration file `named.conf` Typically there will be a unique zone file defined  in your named.conf  for each zone, for each unique domain with the unique entries for that domain.